# How to pass event data from jQuery .on() to a seperate JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, pass-by-value

I've got a jQuery event handler like this:

```
$(document).on("input propertychange", ".qty-target", checkQtyTarget);
```

And a JavaScript function like this:

```
function checkQtyTarget(event) {
        if (isNaN($(this).val())) {
            var x = $(this).val();
            $(this).val(x.slice(0, -1));
            $(this).filter(":not(:animated)").effect("shake");
        }
        else if ($(this).val().length > 3) {
            var x = $(this).val();
            $(this).val(x.slice(0, -1));
            $(this).filter(":not(:animated)").effect("shake");
        }
        else if (event.which === 190) {
            var x = $(this).val();
            $(this).val(x.slice(0, -1));
            $(this).filter(":not(:animated)").effect("shake");
        }
    }
```

When I run Firebug the debugger is telling me event.which isn't defined.  I looked in the jQuery API `.on()` documentation which says you can pass `event.data` as the 3rd parameter of the `.on()` event binding, but when I tried that I got a similar error that `event` wasn't defined.  What am I doing wrong?  How can I pass the `event` data to the separate function?

Comment: Are you sure the event types you are using have a `which` property?

Comment: Ahhhh! You might be right.  Assuming they do, where do I pass the event in the `.on()` call?

Comment: You are already properly passing the event object. `console.log(event)`

Comment: Kevin B, your comment helped me figure out the problem.  When I'm using `input propertychange` there doesn't seem to be an `event` associated with that.  When I made the call with `keyup` it's working perfectly. Thanks!